# MPI loop increases memory usage/ memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, fortran, mpi

I am working on a Fortran program using MPI where an array is split up into strips, each strip is sent to a rank for calculations to be done and then the edge of each array is sent to the rank next to it to update the next timestep. It is an iterative process so each edge is passed to its neighboring rank many times. It works fine, however, as I have started to run the program for larger arrays and more time steps I noticed (via top) that there appears to be a memory leak in that each process is continually increasing the amount of memory it is using. If I run the program long enough eventually it uses up all the system memory and crashes my machine.

All I am trying to do is send a string of data from one rank to another many times in a row, I don't know why the memory should be increasing from passing this information. Below is an example which exhibits the behavior. Am I somehow not releasing the passed data from memory which is causing it to build up over time?

(EDIT: changed example code to reflect comment below)

```
Program main

use mpi

REAL(KIND=KIND(0.0D0)) ::putbuf ( 1000 ), getbuf ( 1000 )
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: from = 2, to = 3,fromtag = 123, totag = 456
INTEGER, DIMENSION(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: status
INTEGER :: error, rank

!  Initialize MPI.
  call MPI_Init ( error )
!  Get the number of processes.
  call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, error )
!  Get the individual process ID.
  call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, error )


do i = 1,50000000
putbuf = i
if (rank == 0) then
    CALL MPI_Sendrecv ( putbuf, 1000,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 1, 123,getbuf, 1000, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,&
    1, 456,MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, error )
else
    CALL MPI_Sendrecv ( putbuf, 1000,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, 456,getbuf, 1000, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,&
    0, 123,MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, error )
endif
enddo

call MPI_Finalize ( error )
endprogram
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem as you report it, though the program above runs so quickly and uses so little memory that it is difficult to see anything. So could you expand the above program a little in some way to better illustrate the problem? It would also help to tell us what compiler and MPI you are using - I ran the above with gcc 4.8.5 and openmpi 1.6.5 on a single 4 core box running Ubuntu 14.04.4

Comment: Memory leak??? most of the time, it happens because you are using pointers and are allocating without deallocating. That is just a suggestion because I can see any pointer in your sample program, and I hope it is the case in your real program.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am using  gcc 5.1.0 and openmpi 1.8.6 on a dual 4 core MacPro with OS X 10.10.5. It may very well be an implementation error, I am gonna track down a different box and try and run it on there to test. If you change either the size of putbuf or the number of iterations it should increase the memory usage per process (if you get the same problem I get). If I set the passed data size to 1000 and iterations to 50000000 (see edit to example code) then I start with <10 Mb per process but end up with +10Gb memory per process (most of it is compressed by the OS).

Comment: Can't reproduce with MacOS X 10.10.5, GCC 5.2.0 and MPICH 3.2.

Comment: no leaks in pasted program under linux with gfortan 5.2.1 and mpich-3.2

Comment: UPDATE:  I reinstalled open-mpi and the leak is plugged so it looks like that was the culprit. Problem is now solved.